# How to run Python GTK+ on osx?

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks, python-3.5, gtk3

I have tried to run my Python3 program with Glade UI in a computer with Mac OSX 10.9.5.

```
$ python3 gedder.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gedder.py", line 7, in <module>
    import gi
ImportError: No module named 'gi'
```

I think should have got the GTK+ when installing Xcode_6.2.dmg from Apple and worked thru https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/OSX/Building .

But how could I get the right `gi` library? When installing it with `pip3` it gives quite ambivalent results. The library is there in Python 3.5 libraries but apparently it has Python2 code:

```
$ pip3 install gi
Collecting gi
  Using cached gi-1.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from gi)
Installing collected packages: gi
  Running setup.py install for gi ... done
Successfully installed gi-1.2

$ python3 gedder.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gedder.py", line 7, in <module>
    import gi
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 39
    print url
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

The program is created in my Ubuntu 16.4 Linux system with Glade 3.18.3 and has `pygobject==3.20` in `pip3 freeze` list.